# MIPS: How to access an array full of zero with loop

Tags: arrays, mips

I have an array like this:

```
r_clues: .word 0 : 512 #  array full of zero
```

I do

```
la $s0, r_clues
lw $t1, 0($s1)
```

and I take the address of first `4` bytes and if i want to take, for example, 4th address i will do

```
lw $t1, 16($s1)
```

because its `4(address) * 4(bytes)`

How i can access to this array with one loop and load word to a register for each `8` bytes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate address of elements and load words.

```
    la $s0, r_clues            # the address
    addiu $s2, $zero, 0        # offset
    addiu $s3, $zero,  64      # number of loops
loop_begin:
    addu $s1, $s0, $s2         # address = base + offset
    lw $t1, 0($s1)             # load the array
    addiu $s2, $s2, 8          # proceed to the next element
    addi $s3, $s3, -1          # substract the counter
    bne $s3, $zero, loop_begin # if there are more elements to load, go to loop
    nop                        # prevent next instruction from being executed before exiting the loop
```

Comment: `addiu $s2, $s2, 8          # proceed to the next element` <-- shouldn't that be a 4?

Comment: @Michael I guess no because the question says "for each `8` bytes"

Comment: Ah, right. I got confused because the question also talked about the _"4th address"_ being `16($s1)`.

Comment: This is a very good solution, but i can't understand why you substract the counter by -1 each time

Comment: When you initialize the counter to 64 you mean 64 bytes, right ? Don't we have to substract the counter - 4 (bytes) to load each word (maybe I ought to say load each word to my question)

Comment: No, the counter value 64 means 64 *elements*.